# Wavefunction Problem wrong in solutions manual?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, textbook-erratum

Well there is a problem in my book which lists this problem:

> Calculate the probability that a particle will be found at $0.49L$ and $0.51L$ in a box of length $L$ when it has (a) $n = 1$. Take the wave function to be constant in this range.

The answer in the solutions manual for this specific problem is given as:

[image: Solution]

However when I workout the equation myself I get this:

[image: What I got]

So i don't understand why the solutions book says that:
$$\frac{2}{L}\int \sin^2 \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) \; \mathrm{d} x  \approx \frac{2 \Delta x}{L} \sin^2 \left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right)$$

What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 1):

The solution manual just uses a simple midpoint approximation to evaluate the integral. Doing it the way you did it should be fine as well. You just need to include both terms when you plug the limits of the integral into the antiderivate. I think you just did the $x/2$ term but not the $\sin$ term.

Comment: Thank you for the midpoint approximation explanation. Really really helpful and helped me solved this confusing problem (so simple!!). What do you mean by your second statement? I believe I integrated both terms and applied both terms efficiently.

Comment: I don't agree that doing it the way @Biochemist_HK did is necessarily fine. That answer is (modulo any computational errors I'm not seeing) correct; however, the question specifically instructs that the wavefunction be taken to be constant over range of interest. Understanding how to make approximations is an important skill too, which is likely the rationale behind this question. Doing the antiderivative is not solving the problem as it's presented.

Comment: @Biochemist_HK you got an answer of .02, but the correct answer should be closer to .04 as the solution manual pionts out. I am not sure where your confusion is, so try doing the procedure outlined [here](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/Engineering%20maths%20first%20aid%20kit/latexsource%20and%20diagrams/8_9.pdf) to do your definite integral, and you should get an answer much closer to .04. If this still doesn't work, then you should show your work of evaluating the integral, so I can see what you did wrong.

Comment: @dgh you raise a good point. The main point I was trying to make was that the way he did it should be fine in the sense of giving a similar answer. His answer is not different because of the approximation; it is different because he evaluated his integral wrong.